# Spark read performance difference in same size but with different row lengths

Tags: apache-spark, amazon-s3, apache-spark-sql, performance-testing

I am using spark sql to read 2 different datasets sitting in ORC format in S3 . But the performance difference in reading is huge for almost similar size datasets.

Dataset 1 : contains **212,000,000 records** each with **50 columns** and total up to **15GB** in orc format in s3 bucket .

Dataset 2 : contains **29,000,000 records** each with **150 columns** and total up to **15GB** in orc format in same s3 bucket .

Dataset 1 is taking **2 mins** to read using spark sql. And its taking **12 mins** to read Dataset 2 with same spark read/count job in same infrastructure.

Length of each row could cause this big difference. Can anyone help me understand the reason behind huge performance difference in reading these datasets ?

Answer (score 3):

Assuming you are using the s3a: client (and not Amazon EMR & it's s3:// client)
it is about how much seek() work is going on and whether the client is being clever about random IO or not. Essentially: seek() is very expensive over HTTP1.1 GETs if you have to close an HTTP connection and create a new one. Hadoop  2.8+ adds two features for this: [HADOOP-14244](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HADOOP-12444): Lazy seek, and [HADOOP-13203](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HADOOP-13203). High performance random IO.

If you have the Hadoop 2.8.+ JARs on your classopath, go:

```
spark.hadoop.fs.s3a.experimental.input.fadvise random
```

This will hurt performance on non-random IO (reading .gz files and the like), but is critical for ORC/Parquet IO perf.

If you are using Amazon EMR, their s3 client is closed source, take it up with their support team I'm afraid.

Comment: I am using Amazon EMR and their s3 client.. Anything I can try to test performance? Note: No. of files are more in Dataset 1 (300 against 220 in dataset 2 )

Comment: I suspect its more the amount of skipping going on than the #of files, though you can try splitting up the files more. To test performance? , maybe start locally with an installaion of Hadoop 2.8 & spark with "user supplied JARs" https://spark.apache.org/downloads.html ... stick it in a VM and turn that seek on-off against the second dataset. Other strategy. Download it all locally & compare perf in file:// .. that can be a benchmark

Comment: I think that the above configuration key contains a typo: I believe that this should be `spark.hadoop.fs.s3a.experimental.input.fadvise` (the `.input` was missing).

Comment: Josh: well caught, and kind of embarrassing for me, given it's my constant. Fixed.